# Can't stop/restart Apache2 service

Tags: linux, debian, apache2, init.d

Trying to stop Apache2 service, but get PID error:

```
#service apache2 stop

[FAIL] Stopping web server: apache2 failed!
[....] There are processes named 'apache2' running which do not match your pid file which are left untouched in the name of safety, Plea[warnview the situation by hand. ... (warning).
```

Trying to kill, those processes:

```
#kill -9 $(ps aux | grep apache2 | awk '{print $2}')
```

but they get re-spawned again:

```
#ps aux | grep apache2
root     19279  0.0  0.0   4080   348 ?        Ss   05:10   0:00 runsv apache2
root     19280  0.0  0.0   4316   648 ?        S    05:10   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND
root     19282  0.0  0.0  91344  5424 ?        S    05:10   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND
www-data 19284  0.0  0.0 380500  2812 ?        Sl   05:10   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND
www-data 19285  0.0  0.0 380500  2812 ?        Sl   05:10   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND
```

And though the processes are running i can't connect to the server on port 80. /var/log/apache2/error.log.1 has no new messages when i do the kill -9.
Before I tried to restart everything worked perfectly.
Running on Debian: Linux adara 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.54-2 x86_64 GNU/Linux

UPD:
also tried apache2ctl:

```
#/usr/sbin/apache2ctl -k stop
AH00526: Syntax error on line 76 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
PidFile takes one argument, A file for logging the server process ID
Action '-k stop' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

but there is no pid file in /var/run/apache2

I'm new to linux, looks like it has to do something with startup scripts, but can't figure out what exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Below  is the command to find out the process running on port 80

lsof -i tcp:80

Kill the process with PID.Restart the  system once to check if their is any start up  script  executing and using the Port 80 which is preventing you to start your service.

For start up scripts you can check

/etc/init.d/  or /etc/rc.local or crontab - e

Comment: there are other services on this server, unfortunately, can't restart it so easily, but i will certainly do later if i don't find other solution. lsof -i tcp:80 doesn't return anything

Answer (score -1):

You can try Apache official documentation for stop/restart operations.
[link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/stopping.html)

Comment: kill doesn't work (processes get re-spawned again), apache2ctl -k stop requires pid file, but it's missing